# Invalid Type Error

Tags: apex, query, controller, error

I am trying to fetch a list in my controller but I am not able to query the object directly and not even able to declare an empty list in my class

Here is how I am declaring this in my class

```
List<AccountUserTerritory2View> aosj=New List<AccountUserTerritory2View>();
```

When I try to save it in my class it says

```
line 12, col 1. Invalid type: AccountUserTerritory2View
```

When I am trying to paste the same in some other controller created by someone else it is getting saved without any errors

Note I am able to query and create the list from the dev console anonymous window

When I create a class by logging as some other user I am able to save this and later edit it as my user

Comment: What is your class API version?

Comment: how and where you have created `AccountUserTerritory2View` class?

Comment: It's a custom object

Comment: If it's a custom object then it should be __c i.e. AccountUserTerritory2View but this name looks like Apex Class.

Comment: `AccountUserTerritory2View__c`.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of it being a custom object you will need to reference it using myCustomObject__c so in your case just do.

```
List<AccountUserTerritory2View__c> aosj = New List<AccountUserTerritory2View__c>();
```

That should resolve the issue.

For more information on custom objects [see here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on them most recent API. This is not a custom object, it is a standard object but the older API versions do not have it.

Answer (score -3):

Finally I found the issue. Because code is not compiled with the latest version.
If the object needs to work.

Kindly go to top of the developer console , next to code coverage tab, you would get API version dropdown.

Kindly set it as latest version and try to compile the code again to solve the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what everybody told you to do.